# Can Agora or Twilio SDK provide a room for a scheduled event?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, agora.io

I wanted to make an app where the users can schedule an event (think of a webinar). Therefore, the video room should be valid in a future time slot, instead of an immediate invite/attend workflow.

Can Agora or Twilio support this feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Agora.io's Video SDK doesn't set any sort of lifetime or time restrictions on channels.

Within the Agora system, anytime front-end clients connect with the same AppId and Channel Name they will be paired. If you want to build your own "rules"/logic for limiting access based on time and such, you can build this on top of Agora's platform.

Using Agora.io's SDK, whenever a client *(broadcaster/audience)* uses the `joinChannel` method, it makes a request to the Agora SDRTN to join the given channel. If the channel does not exist, Agora's system will create the channel and add the client into it. Then any other client's who request to join this channel will be added.

## *Update*

To expand upon this answer, the Agora team recommends using token based security to better control which users can join channels. Agora tokens are how your app lets Agora's network know that this user has been authenticated and should be allowed to join a channel. Setting up am Agora Token server to generate tokens is pretty easy. Here are a few guides the Agora DevRel team have written:

- [Golang Token Server](https://medium.com/agora-io/how-to-build-a-token-server-for-agora-applications-using-golang-302f55d95289)
- [Node JS](https://medium.com/agora-io/building-a-token-server-for-agora-applications-using-node-js-15f9445c3e89)

Comment: Is this answer still valid? I have a similar use case, where users should be able to join pre-scheduled and recurring events(classrooms).

Comment: yes this answer is still valid.